# F# match pattern for Expr<int>

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, f#-3.0, quotations

I try to find the correct pattern to match and run an `Expr<int>` using the below code:

```
open System.Linq

open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

let runSelectQuery (q:Expr<IQueryable<'T>>) = 
    match q with
    | Application(Lambda(builder, Call(Some builder2, miRun, [Quote body])), queryObj) ->
        query.Run(Expr.Cast<Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuerySource<'T, IQueryable>>(body))
    | _ -> failwith "Cannot run this query %s" (q.ToString())

let runCountQuery (q:Expr<int>) = 
    match q with
    | Application(Lambda(builder, Call(None, miRun, [builder2, Quote body])), queryObj) ->
        query.Run(Expr.Cast<int>(body))
    | _ -> failwith "Cannot run this query %s" (q.ToString())

let countQuery source filter =
    let filter = match filter with | Some filter -> filter | _ -> <@ fun _ -> true @>
    <@ query { for item in source do
               where ((%filter) item)
               count } @>
```

The runSelectQuery correctly matches the `Expr<IQueryable<'T>>` pattern. However, I cannot find the correct pattern to match my generic count query `Expr<int>`

The pattern in the code I derived from the signature of countQuery gives me a:

> This expression was expected to have type
>       Expr     but here has type
>       'a * 'b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! Stupidly I first tried to match the array pattern using a comma separated pattern (as is the list delimiter in C#), that obviously did not work in F# complaining the it was not a list but a tupple and thus not a Rex.

To match agains an int result or any 'T result:

```
let runQueryToQueryable (q:Expr<IQueryable<'T>>) = 
    match q with
    | Application(Lambda(builder, Call(Some builder2, miRun, [Quote body])), queryObj) ->
        query.Run(Expr.Cast<Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuerySource<'T, IQueryable>>(body))
    | _ -> failwith "Cannot run this query %s" (q.ToString())

let runQueryToType (q:Expr<'T>) = 
    match q with
    | Application(Lambda(builder, Call(None, miRun, [builder2; Quote body])), queryObj) ->
           query.Run(Expr.Cast<'T>(body))
    | _ -> failwith "Cannot run this query %s" (q.ToString())
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: It was just a typo :)